# Entity Framework Core not filling object by foreign key on update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I see this error when updating an `Application`. The object has two external connections: `ApplicationVisitors` and `ApplicationPlatforms`. The properties in `Application` have been updated, but external connections was not be updated.
What am I doing wrong? How to update `Application` correctly?

Route

```cs
[Route("update")]
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateApplication(ApplicationDTO applicationDTO)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
         return BadRequest("Модель не валидна!");

     await applicationService.UpdateApplication(applicationDTO);
     return Ok();
}
```

Service

```cs
public async Task UpdateApplication(ApplicationDTO applicationDTO)
{
      var visitors = Mapper.ToVisitors(applicationDTO.ApplicationVisitors);
      var visitorsToCreate = visitors.Where(w => w.Id == 0).ToList();
      var createdVisitors = visitors.Where(w => w.Id > 0).ToList();

      var resultCreateVisitors = await _wrapper.Visitor.CreateVisitorsAsync(visitorsToCreate);
            createdVisitors.AddRange(resultCreateVisitors);

      applicationDTO.ApplicationVisitors = Mapper.ToVisitors(createdVisitors);

      await _wrapper.Application.UpdateAsync(Mapper.ToApplication(applicationDTO));
}
```

Repository method

```cs
public async Task UpdateAsync(Application application)
{
      Update(application);
      await SaveAsync();
}
```

BaseRepository

```cs
public void Update(T entity)
{
      _repositoryContext.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
      _repositoryContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

public async Task SaveAsync()
{
      await _repositoryContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I have not any exeption in debug. `Application` was filled by ID, but `Platform` and `Visitor` in collections `ApplicationPlatforms` and `ApplicationVisitors` does not filling by foreign key.
References is existing in classes.
[view result Attach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvPgj.png)

Application

```
public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName="date")]
    public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }
    public int ApproverId { get; set; }
    public User Approver { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationStatus Status { get; set; }
    public string VisitPurpose { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get;set; }
    public User Author { get; set; }
    public IList<Draft> Drafts { get; set; }
    public IList<ApplicationVisitor> ApplicationVisitors { get; set; }
    public IList<ApplicationPlatform> ApplicationPlatforms { get; set; }
    public IList<Pass> Passes { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationVisitor

```
public class ApplicationVisitor
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationId")]
    public Application Application { get; set; }
    public int VisitorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VisitorId")]
    public Visitor Visitor { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationPlatform

```
public class ApplicationPlatform
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationId")]
    public Application Application { get; set; }
    public int PlatformId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PlatformId")]     
    public Platform Platform { get; set; }
}
```

**UPD: 22.10.2019. This is my solution what working for me on base selected answer!**

I rewrited update method in `ApplicationRepository`

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(Application application)
{
    var app = await GetAsync(application.Id);

    app.DateStart = application.DateStart;
    app.DateEnd = application.DateEnd;
    app.ApproverId = application.ApproverId;
    app.StatusId = application.StatusId;
    app.VisitPurpose = application.VisitPurpose;
    app.CreatedAt = application.CreatedAt;
    app.AuthorId = application.AuthorId;
    app.ApplicationVisitors = application.ApplicationVisitors;
    app.ApplicationPlatforms = application.ApplicationPlatforms;

    Update(app);
    await SaveAsync();
}
```

And rewrided method in my `BaseRepository`

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
    _repositoryContext.Set<T>().Update(entity);
}
```

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking

Comment: @TheGeneral, I am sorry. I was edited post.

Comment: @TheGeneral, please, check my edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you attached the Application object and set its state to Modified, all other objects references by it will be in Unchanged state, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-3.0):

> For entity types with generated keys if an entity has its primary key
>   value set then it will be tracked in the Unchanged state. If the
>   primary key value is not set then it will be tracked in the Added
>   state. This helps ensure only new entities will be inserted. An entity
>   is considered to have its primary key value set if the primary key
>   property is set to anything other than the CLR default for the
>   property type.

You can either manually set the state of all referenced objects or, A better approach in my option, is to load the objects from the database (and have EF track them for changes) and modify these objects. These way EF will know the exact state for each object when it comes to save it to the database.

Comment: Thanks! I rewrited some code and is working for me. I posted my result in the end in my question.

Comment: But if exists most correctly solution, share with me them, please.